# Javascript autocloses HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, innerhtml

Why do these two functions give different results?

```js
var table1 = document.getElementById("table1");
var table2 = document.getElementById("table2");

var register = [
  {att1: 1, att2: 2, att3: 3},
  {att1: 4, att2: 5, att3: 6},
  {att1: 7, att2: 8, att3: 9}
];

//table1.innerHTML = "";
//table2.innerHTML = "";

function drawTable1() {
  for (var i = 0; i < register.length; i++) {
    table1.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + register[i].att1 + "</td><td>" + register[i].att2 + "</td><td>" + register[i].att3 + "</td></tr>";
  }
}

function drawTable2() {
 for (var i = 0; i < register.length; i++) {
   table2.innerHTML += "<tr>";
    table2.innerHTML += "<td>" + register[i].att1 + "</td>";
    table2.innerHTML += "<td>" + register[i].att2 + "</td>";
    table2.innerHTML += "<td>" + register[i].att3 + "</td>";
    table2.innerHTML += "</tr>";
  }
}

drawTable1();
drawTable2();
```

```css
table {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Att1</th>
        <th>Att2</th>
        <th>Att3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table1">

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Att1</th>
        <th>Att2</th>
        <th>Att3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table2">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

I'm just beginning with js, and I've noticed this thing. From a logical point of view i see no differences between the two functions, the second has just been broken up to make the code easier to read. It should simply be adding strings to a string, but it seems like at every operation the opened tags get closed by the program, resulting in a multitude of rows.

Why is this? How is this useful?

Comment: Headline is wrong - "Javascript" (the JS engine) does no such thing, it only knows strings, not "HTML tags". That's the browser's HTML => DOM parser at work, which is not part of "Javascript".but of the browser. Javascript is allowed to send strings there and to manipulate and query the DOM, but the methods for all of that are "browser".

Comment: Thank you everyone! It makes sense now. I saw the browser as a simple interpreter for html code, my thought was that any error in the code would simply lead to errors in rendering, I did not realize that it is actively looking for errors and fixing them, so I linked the issue illustrated in the question to JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`innerHTML` isn't actually a string. It's an interface to the DOM (the elements on the page); reading from it generates a string version of what's currently there, and assigning a value to it modifies the tree.

It's impossible to have an unclosed `<tr>` element in the DOM -- when you perform an operation like `table1.innerHTML += "<tr>"`, the browser sees the unclosed `<tr>` tag as invalid HTML and has to repair it by inserting a closing `</tr>`. When you later access `innerHTML` to perform another modification, you see the "repaired" version, not the value you initially assigned.

The easiest fix will be to build the entire table as a string, then assign to `innerHTML` all at once, e.g.

```
var html = "";
for (...) {
   html += "<tr>";
   html += "<td>example</td>";
   html += "</tr>";
}
table1.innerHTML = html;
```

You may also want to investigate Javascript DOM methods to create HTML elements (like `document.createElement()`) as an alternative -- `innerHTML` is a clumsy interface.

Comment: Specifically, `innerHTML` is a way of serializing and parsing the DOM. In the case of setting `innerHTML`, it's [parsed with this algorithm](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#parsing).

Answer (score 1):

Well the `innerHTML` content is — as the name implies — HTML and HTML is **not just a string**. I assume you know that browsers build a DOM out of it. Basically a tree out of nodes that know their tag, attributes, children etc.

Now you need this DOM to render anything. Sure, it is nearly impossible to get invalid html as non-html can just be interpreted as a mere string (which is valid html). However, the browser tries to fullfill the html standard as much as possible. Therefore it also generates missing end tags in order to produce well-formed html. (even when it is not in the html, he will implicitely generate them for the DOM and in some browsers you can see that in the HTML provided in the dev console).

So now you add a random `<tr>` attribute to your html like this `table2.innerHTML += "<tr>"`. This would produce not-well-formed html. Therefore it **should** generate the missing end tag. Whether that is done while running the js-code or afterwards when refreshing the DOM, I don't know, but generally it helps generate well-formed HTML.

---

I'm sure you know how to circumvent that problem, but anyways: Instead of using an temporary string, you might want to look at [`document.createElement()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp). This is generally used to generate well-formed html in a non-confusing and safe (as in "something unexpected like above doesn't happen safe") way.